# Can a C++ constructor return a pointer to a cached version of an identical object?

Tags: c++, pointers, caching, constructor

Let's say I have a class `Bitmap` that has a static cache map `textures` that holds pointers to all images that have been registered.

```cpp
class Bitmap {
public:
    Bitmap(const std::string &filename);

    // ... functionality ...

private:
// ... image data ...
    std::string filename;
    static std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Bitmap>> images;
}
```

Is it possible for the constructor of `Bitmap` to search the cache for an existing object with the same `filename` and then return a reference to that?

I've tried something like

```cpp
if (images.find(filename) != images.end()) {
    *this = images[filename].get();
    return;
}
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Is there a way at all to achieve this effect using the constructor?

Comment: No, it must create a new object. Maybe use a static function or free function for what you want to achieve?

Comment: A constructor doesn't *return* anything. What does your "image data" look like?

Comment: This sounds like you want a factory function, not a constructor.

Comment: Sounds like you might want a factory function backed up by an object cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the time you're actually constructing an object, you're already outside the scope of controlling the object's allocation. The constructor is simply there to initialize the object.

One way to achieve this with minimal changes to your code is to make the constructor private and create a static method to perform the create/cache logic.

```
class Bitmap {
public:
    static Bitmap& Get(const std::string &filename);

private:
    Bitmap(const std::string &filename)
        : filename(filename)
    {
        std::cout << "Construct " << filename << "\n";
    }

    std::string filename;
    static std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Bitmap>> images;
};

std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Bitmap>> Bitmap::images;

Bitmap& Bitmap::Get(const std::string &filename)
{
    auto it = images.find(filename);
    if (it == images.end())
    {
        std::unique_ptr<Bitmap> ptr(new Bitmap(filename));
        it = images.insert(std::make_pair(filename, std::move(ptr))).first;
    }
    return *(it->second);
}
```

Driver code:

```
int main()
{
    auto a = Bitmap::Get("foo");
    auto b = Bitmap::Get("bar");
    auto c = Bitmap::Get("foo");
}
```

Output:

```
Construct foo
Construct bar
```

This essentially turns your `Bitmap` class into a self-managing cache. If you want to allow both cached and uncached bitmap instances, then you would move the caching stuff to a separate factory class such as `BitmapManager`.

Comment: You can greatly simplify the implementation of `Get()` if you use `map::operator[]` instead of `map::find()`+`map::insert()`, eg: `Bitmap& Bitmap::Get(const std::string &filename) { auto &ptr = images[filename]; if (!ptr) { ptr = std::make_unique<Bitmap>(filename); } return *ptr; }`

Comment: I had a brain fart for a moment, but yeah you're right. I normally don't store pointers for caching systems like this. The `std::map` already allocates, so I would usually just use something like `map<string, Bitmap>` unless `Bitmap` can actually be subclassed.

Answer (score 1):

The sane way to make it work is to move all data members to a struct, and store a `std::shared_ptr` to it in the `Bitmap` (and in the static map).